# local root number calculation

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups

For discrete series L-parameter $\phi:W_\mathbb{R}\rightarrow Sp(2n)(\mathbb{C})$
given by Harish-Chandra parameter $(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ with $a_1>\cdots>a_n>0$ and $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}+1/2$. How to calculate the root number $\epsilon(1/2,\phi)$ in terms of $a_1,\cdots,a_n$? Is it true $\epsilon(1/2,\phi)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{a_j+1/2}$? Thanks in advance!

Remark: Note first that $\phi=\bigoplus\limits_i\phi_i$, where $\phi_i:W_\mathbb{R}\rightarrow Sp(2)(\mathbb{C})$ is determined by the Harish-Chandra parameter $(a_i)$. Then by the additive property of $\epsilon$-factor, we have $\epsilon(1/2,\phi)=\prod\limits_{i}\epsilon(1/2,\phi_i)$. Thus the issue is to calculate each $\epsilon(1/2,\phi_i)$ accordingly. On the other hand, $\phi_i|_{\mathbb{C}^\times}: z\mapsto diag((z/\bar{z})^{a_i},(z/\bar{z})^{-a_i})$, then Knapp's article as above tells us that $\epsilon(1/2,\phi_i)=i^{2a_i+1}=(-1)^{a_i+1/2}$. Whence the above identity hold.

Comment: Thanks for your concern! Fortunately, It seems I have found the answer. This results from the basic case of $GL_2$ and the additive property of $\epsilon$-factor. For the $GL_2$ case, one may refer to Knapp's article: Local Langlands correspondence: The Archimedean Case

Comment: it might be a good idea to write what you've found as an answer to your own question.